# How to innerHTML using PlaywrightSharp

Tags: c#, playwright-sharp

I'm trying to set a script on a webpage using PlaywrightSharp but I'm getting errors when using code like this.

```
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await using var browser = await playwright.Firefox.LaunchAsync();
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
var content = await page.GoToAsync(URL);

await page.EvaluateAsync("document.getElementById('#key').innerHTML = 'value';");
await page.ClickAsync("#button");
await page.WaitForLoadStateAsync(LifecycleEvent.Networkidle);
```